# Why am I unable to override Rails' rendering elements with field_with_errors class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm told that by default, if an error occurs in your model, Rails renders your form element set up like so

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price, 'Price', :class => "control-label" %> <span class="required">*</span> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :price, :size => 30 %>
    <div class='error'><%= show_errors(@user_event, :price) %></div>
  </div>
```

as

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label class="control-label" for="user_event_price">Price</label></div> <span class="required">*</span> <br>
    <div class="field_with_errors"><input size="30" value="" name="user_event[price]" id="user_event_price" type="text"></div>
    <div class="error">Please enter a value for price.</div>
  </div>
```

So someone said you should change config/environment.rb and override the default behavior.  I don't want that

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
```

element appearing.  So I set up my file like so

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
    %(<div class="form-field error3">#{html_tag}<small class="error">&nbsp;
      #{instance.error_message.join(',')}</small></div).html_safe
  else
    %(<div class="form-field error3">#{html_tag}<small class="error">&nbsp;
      #{instance.error_message}</small></div).html_safe
  end
end
```

But still my element renders with the "field_with_errors" class.  What am I doing incorrectly above?  I want that element out of there!

**Edit:** Here's the output in response to Gokul's answer

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="form-field error3"><label class="control-label" for="user_event_price">Price</label><small class="error">&nbsp;
      Please enter a value for price.</small></div>* <br>
    <div class="form-field error3"><input size="30" value="" name="user_event[price]" id="user_event_price" type="text"><small class="error">&nbsp;
      Please enter a value for price.</small></div>Please enter a value for price.</div>
```

Comment: Try using simple_form instead, it makes it quite a bit easier to get the markup you want and has ready-built options for Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation.

Comment: I'm confused, use it where?

Comment: simple_form is used instead of the regular rails form helpers. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: And if you want to monkey patch a rails component - don't do it in `config/environment.rb` create a file in config/initializers instead.

Comment: I just want to geet rid of the " <div class="field_with_errors">" message being inserted in my form.  Is it really taht hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an initializer with the following code:

**/config/initializers/format_errors.rb**

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  html_tag.html_safe
end
```

And, don't forgot to restart your server :-)

Comment: Not only does this not work, now the error message prints out three times.  I  included the output as an edit to the question.  Note all I watned to do was remove the '<div class="field_with_errors">' from being rendered.

Comment: @Dave Did you removed the old code in `application.rb` file?

Comment: I did, but I was running behind Apache and I think that was caching some things.  Actually things are now looking real good with your solution.  Let me run a couple more tests and then I'll come back and accept.  Rock on, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

One option is to edit your scaffold.scss style sheet under app/assets/stylesheets. That is where the class is defined. Either a name change or complete removal will do it.

Comment: "<div class="field_with_errors">" is automatically inserted by Rails, so how will editing a stylesheet eliminate taht.  Also, if you want this beautiful bounty, you'll have to ante up some code.

Comment: Correct. Rails inserts the class field_with_errors but the formatting comes from somewhere. In this case it comes from scaffold.scss and removing the style reference removes the formatting called by the fields_with_errors class. I did it and worked great. Only problem is that generating a new scaffold with overwrite your changes unless you tell it not to.